# How to list all pdf files in a directory, sorted in reverse alphabetical order, with bash?

Tags: command-line, files, directory

I have a directory called `all_files`. My script is in the main directory `main_dir` (all_files is a subdirectory of `main_dir`).

`all_files` contains pdf files and only 1 docx file. I want to output all the pdf files' filenames in a reverse alphabetical order. I tried this:

```
tail -r all_files
```

But that includes also that docx file that I want to exclude and it doesn't do the job. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: By "output" do you mean output the file *names*, or their *contents*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` accepts `-r`/`--reverse` to reverse the order of its output. Since its output is in alphabetical order by default, reversing it should do what you want:

```bash
ls -r all_files/*.pdf
```

That shows the prefix `all_files/` on each filename. If you don't want to do that, you can use:

```bash
(cd all_files && ls -r -- *.pdf)
```

The parentheses cause the command to be run in a subshell so that the effect of changing directory to `all_files` does not persist after the command has run (i.e., you stay where you were afterward). The additional `--` argument to `ls` indicates the end of options, which makes it work even in the weird case where one of the `.pdf` files has a name that starts with `-` and that could thus otherwise be interpreted as an option to `ls` rather than as a filename argument.

If you want to list one filename per line regardless of whether or not `ls` is outputting to a terminal (and regardless of the width of the terminal), you can pass `ls` the `-1` option as well:

```bash
ls -1r all_files/*.pdf
```

```bash
(cd all_files && ls -1r -- *.pdf)
```

(Passing the `-1` and `-r` options as two separate arguments also works, and they may be passed in either order. That is, `-1r`, `-r1`, `-1 -r`, and `-r -1` all work and have the same effect.)

Note that `-r`/`--reverse` should not be confused with `-R`/`--recursive`, which would list files in all subdirectories too, and in *their* subdirectories, and so forth. Some programs accept an `-r` option to mean "recursive," but (at least in Ubuntu) `ls -r` performs a reverse listing, not a recursive listing. You can write it out as `ls --reverse` if you prefer. For example:

```bash
ls -1 --reverse all_files/*.pdf
```

---

Since you have all `.pdf` files except one file with a `.docx` extension, `ls -r` on the directory as shown above should be sufficient. However, in the related situation where there were files named many ways but you *only* wanted to omit those named ending in `.docx`, you could use this instead:

```bash
ls -r all_files/!(*.docx)
```

```bash
(cd all_files && ls -r -- !(*.docx))
```

That uses a Bash feature called "extended globbing." This is enabled by default in interactive shells, but not enabled by default in shell scripts. You can check if it is enabled with `shopt extglob`, enable ("set") it with `shopt -s extglob`, and disable ("unset") it with `shopt -u extglob`. You can use a subshell to enable it for just one command, as shown for `cd` above. With that technique, the above two commands become:

```bash
(shopt -s extglob; ls -r all_files/!(*.docx))
```

```bash
(shopt -s extglob; cd all_files && ls -r -- !(*.docx))
```

Comment: That's great thanks. However, it displays the output in three columns. Is there a way to have each name in one line?

Comment: @Jim6834 Yes, you can pass the `-1` option to `ls`. I'll edit this shortly to cover that.